# Having problems with sqrt() in C

Tags: python, c, math, sqrt

While writing a code for my class I managed to create a working example in Python that follows all of the requirements that my professor set out for us to achieve. But when I translate it into C to hand it in to my prof I found several problems that I thought that I managed to circumnavigate but it turns out that I was wrong.

One of the problems that I've found is when in Python I used the following code to determine if the square root is a natural number.

```
if (math.sqrt(a**2+b**2)%2)==1 or (math.sqrt(a**2+b**2)%2)==0:
```

When I translated this in C I found that I was getting error messages while trying to compile the code saying that I was trying to modulo floats with integers and a whole lot of other stuff.

I did a few test runs in C to get a feel of the environment around roots and found that a variable assigned as a float or double returns 0 if the root is a natural number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    float r_float_a, r_float_b;
    int a=16,b=15,r_int_a,r_int_b;
    r_float_a=sqrt(a);
    r_float_b=sqrt(b);
    r_int_a=sqrt(a);
    r_int_b=sqrt(b);
    printf("%d\n",r_float_a);
    printf("%d\n",r_float_b);
    printf("%d\n",r_int_a);
    printf("%d\n",r_int_b);
}
```

But if I were to try to call out r_float_a in a if statement it would always return false no matter the value of a:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    float r_float_a, r_float_b;
    int a=16,b=15,r_int_a,r_int_b;
    r_float_a=sqrt(a);
    r_float_b=sqrt(b);
    r_int_a=sqrt(a);
    r_int_b=sqrt(b);
    printf("%d\n",r_float_a);
    printf("%d\n",r_float_b);
    if (r_float_a==0)
    {
        printf("%d\n",r_int_a);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d\n",r_int_b);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this to be able to check if the square root of a number is a natural number?

Comment: Use `%f` to print floats and doubles.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, if the number's square root is a natural (integer) number, so is the number itself.

```
unsigned a = 15;
unsigned root = (unsigned)sqrt(a);
if (root * root == a)
    printf("%u has the natural square root %u\n", a, root);
else
    printf("%u does not have a natural square root\n", a);
```

I used `unsigned` because a natural number is a whole, non-negative number. Therefore the use of `signed` numbers is outside the scope of this question. A square root can be negative but that would not be a natural number. The square root of a *negative* number enters the realm of *complex* numbers.

Comment: I'm sure future users would find it helpful.

Comment: Could you explain unsigned I think I know why but it would be nice to know for sure

Answer (score 0):

OP's and [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33046090/2410359) methods fail for large `float`.  `float` typically has 6 to 8 decimal digits of precision.   For numbers larger than `1e14`, the `sqrt()`, saved as a `float`, will always be a whole number - convertible exactly to an integer (if in the integer range).

To determine if a `float x` is an exact square of another whole number:

1. Test if `x` is negative, INF or NaN and fail those pathological cases.
2. Use `modff()` to extract the fractional portion and if not 0.0, fail.
3. Use `fmodf()` to extract the mantissa/significand and exponent.  Examine the exponent.  Factor out even powers above the `float` bit width - reform `x` and *then* apply [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33046090/2410359) test.